# how to move from one screen to another screen ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have home screen and login screen.And i need pop or model to open my login screen fully.without back button or push . How to do that.so far i have use push. but i need model or pop to show my login screen.

html :

```
onclikc = goToSomethingElse
```

js:

```
  goToSomethingElse() {
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);

}
```

how can i do with pop or model.I have seen the navigationcontroller doc.but not able to get clear. any code example will be help full.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ModalController:

```
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';


constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController){}

 public goToSomethingElse() {
   let loginModal = this.modalCtrl.create(LoginPage);
   loginModal.present();

 }
```

Comment: thanks .  am also struck in this issue too. no solutions found. can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695743/ionic-2-navbar-left-and-right-button-not-working

Comment: i have one problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716187/ionic-2-back-button-or-any-icon-is-not-showing-only-small-box-icon-is-showing